# pyodbc 4.0.13: Not support unicode sql statement in Chinese

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, pyodbc

SOURCE CODE:

```
# coding=utf8

import pyodbc

print pyodbc.version

sql = u"""SELECT
    N'我的' AS [Name]
"""


def test_success():
    conn = pyodbc.connect(u'Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=mydb;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
        unicode_results=True)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute(sql)
    print "test_success::"
    print "." * 80
    # data = cursor.fetchall()
    print "." * 80


test_success()
```

Got errors:

```
PS C:\Users\vincent\Documents\GitHub> python C:\Users\vincent\Downloads\pyodbctest.py
4.0.13
test_success::
................................................................................
................................................................................
Exception UnicodeEncodeError: UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', u"SELECT\n    N'\u6211\u7684' AS [Name]\n", 13, 15, 'ordinal not in range(128)') in <module 'threading' from 'C:\Python27\lib\threading.pyc'> ignored
```

Does anyone knows is it a bug or I just wrote wrong code?

And it's very strange that print statements run successful but the error is from `cursor.execute(sql)`

Comment: This issue is also being discussed on [GitHub](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/206).

Comment: It's my question, just want more people see it

Answer (score 0):

I have search a lot by google but no answer for me. So I downgrade the pyodbc version to [3.1.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyodbc/3.1.1), which is the last version before version 4, it works fine for me and I didn't find a similar problem since now.

My answer for this issue now is: Using the last stable pyodbc version: 3.1.1

Comment: A code change [has been committed](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/commit/13cf3503289dadbcad20083211128849e6d20ac7) to fix this issue in pyodbc version 4.0.14.